# How to perform two searches at once in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I often find myself performing one search immediately followed by another search. I am wondering if I can combine the two searches into one command.

For example, if I want to find the first instance of the `foobar` variable within a function named `transmogrify`, I would enter:

```
/def transmogrify
/foobar
```

Or if I'm in a log file and I want to search for an error that happened after a specific date:

```
/2012-07-26
/ERROR
```

Is there a better way to do this? And no, I'm not looking to record a macro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest might be, e.g.

```
/def transmogrify/;/foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|` symbol to do an OR operation when searching.

Taking your second example, for example:

```
/2012-07-26\|ERROR
```

Even better, if you have these set in your vimrc:

```
" Make search expressions "very magic"
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
```

Then you don't have to escape the `|`. E.g.:

```
/\v2012-07-26|ERROR
```

Comment: In my brain that wouldn't work because it should stop once it finds the first term because that makes the whole statement true, but in real life it probably does work.

Comment: @Rob is right; this didn't work when I just tested it. Thanks, though!

Comment: It sort of works. It will get you what you want, you'll have to navigate through all the `foobar` or `error` though. It doesn't not work because of what I said, but because it matches both terms, which is what the `|` is for here.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I misunderstood what you were asking for.